# I have an iPod 5 gen, how do I view my wifi password? I've lost the wifi password

Tags: ios, wifi, security

My iPod 5 gen is connected to wifi, I've lost the wifi password, how can I view the password on my iPod, could you please give me a step by step guide on doing this as I'm not tech savvy....

Answer (score 1):

You can't see it on Iphone.   Security issue.   If you access the router from OSX it will be in Keychain access.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot view the password directly on your iOS device. (See [Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3132894?start=0&tstart=0))
Allowing you to do that would be a security flaw, as it could make it easy for someone to casually check the wifi password on an iPod or iPhone and then get on the network. Instead, you should find the IP address and enter that into your browser's web bar most of the time.

You are probably in one of a few situations:

1. You are on your own personal home wifi network.  If that is the case, you can get onto your router and reset your wifi password, or perhaps even view it there.
2. You are on a wifi network owned and maintained by someone else.  If this is the case, ask them for the wifi password.

In either of the above cases, if you have a Macbook that has the wifi password stored, you can likely recover it via the Keychain Access utility.